# NameResolutionFailure Nightmare: Even ModernHttpClient is failing

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am constantly getting `NameResolutionFailure` errors when I make web requests (GET) in my MVVM Cross Android app.

I've tried out much of the advice provided in forums re this issue as it's a common one but I am unable to fix this.

My current attempt uses the NuGet package `ModernHttpClient` to perform web requests. The same error occurs - unable to resolve the domain to an IP - however the error message is slightly different from what was happening when I was using `HttpWebRequest` so I guess thats a slight improvement?

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com": No address associated with hostname

Can you provide advice on why this is always failing? Maybe its my method thats not truely utilising `ModernHttpClient`?

The following code is part of my `IRestService` class located in the `Core` PCL and not in the Android project.

```
public async Task MakeRequest(WebHeaderCollection headers = null)
{

    var handler = new NativeMessageHandler();
    string requestUrl = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";

    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            //client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                Mvx.Trace("Stream: {0}", reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Mvx.Trace("MakeRequest Error: '{0}'", ex.Message);
    }

    return;
}
```

*PS:* I have also attempted to use Cheesebarons ModernHttpClient MVVM Cross plugin but this is causing compile errors in release mode and there is no documentation about what methods and classes it has - maybe its not supported anymore?

*PPS:* And yes my manifest has internet permission (I check the options and the actual manifest file to confirm)

Comment: Some folks are saying it could be a network problem. Have you tried another network, including cellular? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7327/system-net-webexception-error-nameresolutionfailure

Comment: @Eraph Thanks for your comment. I have tried home wifi, portable wifi thumbdrive and 4g no luck unfortunately

Comment: Also this fails on my Genymotion emulator (Nexus) and actual Huawei phone. And like others are saying it was working a couple of weeks ago using `HttpWebRequest` and just all of the sudden now doesn't.

Comment: try posting on xamarin official forum also, there Cheesebaron is more active and he use this name for username, you can include him in the topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ModernHttpClient plugin for MvvmCross is not needed anymore, so don't use it.

So since you have Internet permission set in the AndroidManifest the problem is something else. I've experienced on some Android devices, that the first call to some Internet resource fails with the same error you get. The way I've usually worked around that is to retry the call.

There are various ways to do so.

1. You can create your own HttpClientHandler which wraps the one coming from ModernHttpClient and create your own retry handling in there.
2. You can retry using a library such as Polly

I tend to do the latter. So if you add the Polly NuGet you can pretty quickly test out if this solves the problem for you:

```
var policy = Policy.WaitAndRetryAsync(
    5, 
    retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
    (ex, span) => {
        Mvx.Trace("Retried because of {0}", ex);
    }
);
```

Then retry your task like:

```
await policy.ExecuteAsync(() => MakeRequest(someHeaders)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Usually on second try the exception goes away.

I've seen this problem on Nexus 5, Nexus 7 and on an Samsung Galaxy SII, but not on other devices. It might also help if you toggle the WiFi on the device prior to debugging.

In any case, you app should have some kind of retry logic as Internet connections can be spotty at times.

Comment: Thank you! I could kiss you :P Been struggling with this for days.